# How to update/refresh a ListView in Xaml (windows 8 app) manually?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I need to refresh/update a ListView in my App. Since using INotifyPropertyChanged wouldn't be usefull in my case, is there any way to do this? I saw explanations for this in WPF but they do not work.

What i tried so far:

```
this.itemListView.Update();
this.itemListView.Items.Update();
this.itemListView.Refresh();
this.itemListView.Items.Refresh();

this.itemListView.UpdateLayout();
```

none of them worked.

also the final one did not work, even if it should be, because it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reset my ItemSource:

```
itemListView.ItemsSource = group.Items
```

Answer (score 1):

im going through the same thing, 
i tried to nullify the ItemsSource and assignig it again, 
something like :

```
itemListView.ItemsSource = null;
itemListView.ItemsSource = group.Items;
```